# ordering union results with CTEs

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, common-table-expression

How can I use ORDER BY when I have couple of CTEs followed by UNION of SELECTs. My query is like this:

```
WITH
cte1 AS (SELECT * FROM table1),
cte2 AS (SELECT * FROM table2),
cte3 AS (SELECT * FROM table3)
SELECT cte1.column1,cte1.column2 FROM cte1
UNION
SELECT cte2.column1,cte2.column2 FROM cte2
UNION
SELECT cte3.column1,cte3.column2 FROM cte3
```

and I need to order the results by column1 which in all CTEs is an integer number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `order by`:

```
WITH cte1 AS (SELECT * FROM table1),
cte2 AS (SELECT * FROM table2),
cte3 AS (SELECT * FROM table3)
SELECT cte1.column1,cte1.column2 FROM cte1
UNION
SELECT cte2.column1,cte2.column2 FROM cte2
UNION
SELECT cte3.column1,cte3.column2 FROM cte3
order by column1 --<< here
```

An `order by` on a union always orders the complete union, not just the last select.

---

Btw: you might also want to read up on the difference between `union` and `union all`. If you know you don't have duplicates between the individual select (or don't care), `union all` will be faster.